# Luhn function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, luhn

I'm currently working through the book [Programming in Haskell](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/pih.html) (which is absolutely amazing so far), but ran into a problem in exercise 4.8.8.

The task is to implement the *[Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm)* in Haskell, using a help function `luhnDouble :: Int -> Int` (which doubles a digit and subtracts 9 if the result is greater than 9) and the `mod` funcion.

Implementing the `luhnDouble` function was no problem, but I'm struggling to bring both of them into a function of type `Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool`.

I have tried doing it two ways:

```
luhn :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
luhn w x y z = if (((luhnDouble w) + x + (luhnDouble y) + z) mod 10) == 0 then True
               else False
```

I receive a type error.

```
* Couldn't match expected type `(Integer -> Integer -> Integer)
                                -> Integer -> Integer'
              with actual type `Int'
* The function `(luhnDouble w) + x + (luhnDouble y) + z'
  is applied to two arguments,
  but its type `Int' has none
  In the first argument of `(==)', namely
    `(((luhnDouble w) + x + (luhnDouble y) + z) mod 10)'
  In the expression:
    (((luhnDouble w) + x + (luhnDouble y) + z) mod 10) == 0
```

But am I not giving the functions 4 `Int`s as arguments and getting a `Bool` as a result?

I then tried currying the function and using *lambda expressions*:

```
luhn :: Int -> (Int -> (Int -> Bool))
luhn = \w ->(\x ->(\y -> (\z -> ((luhnDouble w) + x + (luhnDouble y) + z mod 10))))
```

But I'm not sure how to bring in the `if` expression in here to get a `Bool` value as a result.

Could anyone help me out, and give me a tip how I could solve this?

Comment: And your `if` expression appears invalid. You're missing an "else" case.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry i forgot. I'll add it in now!

Comment: And you're using `mod` as infix, but don't have it wrapped in backticks, so it's being treated as an argument. That's probably your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
luhn :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
luhn w x y z = if (((luhnDouble w) + x + (luhnDouble y) + z) mod 10) == 0 then True
```

1. You didn't give it an `else` after `if`.
2. You are calling prefix `mod`, not infix `` `mod` ``.

Fix:

```
luhn :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
luhn w x y z = if (((luhnDouble w) + x + (luhnDouble y) + z) `mod` 10) == 0
                  then True
                  else False
```

or

```
luhn :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
luhn w x y z = if (mod ((luhnDouble w) + x + (luhnDouble y) + z) 10) == 0
                  then True
                  else False
```

or, a less redundant version:

```
luhn :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
luhn w x y z = (mod ((luhnDouble w) + x + (luhnDouble y) + z) 10) == 0
```

Comment: I added an edit. Sorry if it conflicts with your intent.

Answer (score 1):

```
luhn :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
luhn w x y z = (luhnDouble w + x + luhnDouble y + z) `mod` 10 == 0
```

This will work